# enable button from another activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I want to enable my btn_test which i set in false. here is my code in mainactivity.java

```
  btn_test= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
     btn_test.setEnabled(false);
```

then in another class, Changactivity.java
i need to set a pattern first

```
if(password.equals(PATTERN_KEY)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pattern created successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChangeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);


                editor.putString("Pattern", password);
                editor.commit();

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

how I can go back to Mainactivity.java and set the btn_test into true??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Changactivity.java after `Intent intent = new Intent(ChangeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);` add `intent.putExtra("state", "success");`.Then, in your MainActivity:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("state")){
  if (getIntent().getStringExtra("state").equals("success")){
  btn_test.setEnabled(true);
  }else{
  btn_test.setEnabled(false);
  }
}else{
  btn_test.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity

and enable button in MainActivity onActivityResult method.